# API Twitter : How can I search users with keywords within BIO fields?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I can't find a way to search users with keywords within BIO fields.
I don't even know if it's possible.
I've already seen that you can't search for users by creation date, but by keyword in a bio, I can't find a topic about this.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use the [v1.1 `users/search` endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search) to search for users. There's currently [no planned replacement in v2, but it is under consideration](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/migrate/twitter-api-endpoint-map).

Comment: With this, I can search users by keywords on they username, I don't find for search users by keywords in bio.

Comment: There is no API for that, apologies for mis-reading your question.